# Spring Data Mongo nested id won't work

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Does Spring Data treats mongo nested "id" attributes differently? I explain my problem: I have collection **matches** with the following structure

```
"teams":  [
        {
            "id" : "5601",
            "name" : "FC Basel"
        },
        ... // more
    ]
```

When I want to retrieve all the matches which has team id 5601 I execute the following query

```
db.matches.find({ "teams.id" : "5601"})
```

Which works perfectly and returns some objects.

When I make a method

```
public List<MatchMongo> findByTeams_id(String id);
```

on my MatchRepository interface I get 0 results back while there are.
Logs shows

```
Created query Query: { "teams.id" : "5601"}, Fields: null, Sort: null

find using query: { "teams.id" : "5601"} fields: null for class: class
MatchMongo in collection: matches
```

So the query he makes seems to be the right one... :S 
Trying with other fields (referee.name for ex.) works.

I even tried with the **@Query** annotation, but can't get it to work

Is there another solution? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you call findById in your TeamsRepository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh found the solution:

MatchMongo had `List<TeamMongo> teams;` on whereI had

```
@Id
private String id;
@Field(value = "id")
private String teamIdAttr;
```

So the method should be called

```
public List<MatchMongo> findByTeams_teamIdAttr(String id);
```

Never thought the method name should reflect objects attributes instead of collection structure

Thanks @martin-baumgartner your comment helped to solve this :)

Comment: I have the same problem, I didn't understand your explication !

Comment: I don't understand your explanation too. Can you explain your solution in more detail please?